# Xcode 10.2 does not open after installation from Mac App Store

Tags: mojave, xcode

When I try to open Xcode 10.2 after installing it from Mac App Store, it doesn't open. After a while, a dialog box comes up with an error

> check with the developer to make sure Xcode works with this version of macOS

I am running macOS Mojave 10.14.2

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Are you trying to launch Xcode directly or by double clicking on a Xcode project/workspace file?

Comment: Precisely **which** Mojave? Xcode 10.2 requires 10.14.3 minimum - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_2_release_notes/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you please [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/360716/edit) the question and specify the exact version of macOS and Xcode that is installed on your Mac?

Comment: @Tetsujin After updating the OS, it is working fine. It was my false assumption that App Store won't allow me to download apps that are not compatible with my OS version. Thank you :)

Comment: I've added that as an answer, just for sake of completeness. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 10.2 requires a minimum macOS of 10.14.3.

It would appear that the App Store doesn't check the minor OS version number before allowing download, leading to this potential for confusion.